# How to Build lora network

Tags: lora, lorawan

I want to make Lora network in india that helps to receive node(sensor) data within 2km to 3km range in urban area.

I had read some tutorial but I have some doubts...

1)can we use single channel gateway without license? (because in india 868mhz is not free)

2)is it required to use TTN server or can we even use our own server to send data from gateway.

3)is lora protocol free to implement?

Answer (score 3):

1. Lora has more than one channel. some of them are between 865.2mhz-867mhz which is free in india. http://www.ensembletech.in/lora-frequency-bands-india/
2. you could use your own server, but the ttn community is really big and you will have good results if you work with them.
3. Once you paid for your hardware, lora is completly free.

Answer (score 1):

1. LoRaWAN works on ISM band, all you need is to pay attention to the send limitation(duty cycle) in each country/area.
2. TTN server is one of open-source LoRaWAN servers. You may build your own server or use other open-source servers.
3. LoRaWAN is open-source and free to implement. You may download latest LoRaWAN specification from official website to get more information.